# classifications for many multiple classes (40)

Tags: classification

I need to classify records in 40 different categories. What would be the best approach to it? Logistic regression? I though it is used for revealed preference and I don't have the other possibilities each line might had. One approach One to one would leave me with 40 taken by 2... a lot of models. IS there any package in R that can solve this type of problem? Also the sample is imbalanced.

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend the R package "randomForest" as a first go. [click](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html)

RF seem to be most accurate across many datasets
[click](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/delgado14a/delgado14a.pdf)

They are robust, there are not many parameters and have no troubles with multiple classes. 
A way to tackle the imbalanced dataset is here [click](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#balance) (with explanation of a lot of other good features of RF)